# Does the Bow of Ashes' flaming ability trigger its special ability?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, weapons

The [Bow of Ashes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/bow-of-ashes) is counted as a [flaming](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/flaming) composite longbow. According to the linked rules regarding flaming, the bow can sheathe itself in flames. The Bow of Ashes has a special ability as follows:

> When the wielder pulls the bowstring while within 5 feet of a flame at least as large as a lit torch, the bow generates and nocks an arrow of rock-hard ash.

Does pulling the bowstring while the bow is flaming trigger this ability? Or does the Bow of Ashes require an external flame to generate an arrow? I am assuming that the flames surrounding the bow meet the size requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a critical footnote on the *flaming* property's entry in Table 15-10: Ranged Weapon Special Abilities (PFRPG CRB, p. 469), which says:

> Bows, crossbows, and slings so crafted bestow the fire energy upon their ammunition.

It's unfortunate that this was omitted from the description itself, because that appears to have led to it being completely omitted from the [PFSRD's entry for *flaming*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/flaming).

### Why this is relevant

Overlooking that all-important note would make *flaming* useless on a ranged weapon unless you planned to beat people with it in melee, because it would only wrap the ranged weapon itself in flames and leaves the ammunition unaltered. But in fact, the *bow itself* does not get wreathed in flames: instead, because the *flaming* property works differently on ranged weapons, it bestows the wreathing flames on the ammunition.

So no, the bow isn't a source of fire to activate its arrow-generation abilities, because it never lights on fire in the first place. The only time it lights anything on fire is when you nock an arrow, which (once on fire) isn't big enough to count as a torch flame. (You can tell it's not big enough to count as a torch flame because it generates so little light that it can't be used as a decent light source, which is far less than the 15' radius of a torch's flame.)

Besides, when you've already nocked an arrow you already have an arrow in the bow and it wouldn't make sense to have a new one be generated.

Comment: PF has this rule as a footnote to the tables listing the weapon enchantments.

Comment: @MrLemon Aha! Odd that it's missing from the description itself. Thank you.

Comment: Makes complete sense that flames only trigger when an arrow is already nocked!

Answer (score 0):

Well, lets see it logically, would that clause be there if the bow counted itself as a lit torch for the purpose of that special ability?
Most likely **No**. It would simply say that while the *Flaming* property is activated it would shoot the ash arrows and be done with it.

I would say that, even if the flaming property lit the bow aflame, which doesn't seem to be the case as per it's description ("burnt wood", but no mention of "flaming"), it still would need another source of fire to trigger the ash arrow ability.

Note how the [Flaming](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/flaming) simply says  "*Upon command, a flaming weapon is sheathed in fire* ", but does not state that the weapon is actually producing any flame. We don't know the size of the flames, it could simply be a thin coat of red-ish heat that burst into flames when a target is hit. So, it has to *successfully strike* a target to deal the fire damage, simply touching the weapon isn't enough to burn things for example.

Keep in mind that even a *+1 Flaming Sword* only has 30% chance when crafted to work as a torch and shed light:

> **Light Generation**: Fully 30% of magic weapons shed light equivalent to a light spell. These glowing weapons are quite obviously magical. Such a weapon can't be concealed when drawn, nor can its light be shut off. Some of the specific weapons detailed below always or never glow, as defined in their descriptions.

On a side note, this bow looks pretty good for assasssins, because 1 round after being shot, the arrow itself will crumble into nothiness and leave no trace of what killed the target, except for a hole on his chest/neck/head/etc.